# Questions on GL10

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have read that `GL10` is a public interface which implements `GL`. My first question is, if `GL10` is an interface how could it implement another interface? Secondly, I directly use the abstract `glClearColor()` method without any definition. Should't I override it first since it is an abstract method?

Reference: [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#glClearColor%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29)

Answer (score -1):

Your first question answer "interface extends"

```
public interface GL10 extends GL {
..
}
```

Second question's ans;

You will use object reference, you wouldn't create new object.

Such as this example;

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this does not say the same: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#glClearColor(float, float, float, float)

Comment: I looked Android Source code(api 14), saw two methods glClearColor(float, float, float, float) second is glClearColorx(int,int,int,int)

Comment: In the given link, written: `public interface GL10 implements GL`. So how could an interface implements another interface?

Comment: Could you look your AndroidSDK/sources/android-<apiversion>/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.java file?